# Getting two parameters from c function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder, codegen

i had a code that c send back 1 number (mex)
the matlab code was

```
vMsg=unit32(Gateway_test_app(2))
```

now i added 1 more return value to Gateway_test_app(2) which is s STRING
what i need to do to get the two values back
i was thinking about something like this:

```
[vMsg,errMsg]=??????(Gateway_test_app(2))
```

what should i put in the ????? place?
thx for any help
johnny.

ps
using codegen and need not to get err when building

Comment: You have to write a function and include the first line inside the code.

Comment: can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

First call the function and store the two outputs, then run your extra function `unit32` (what does it do, by the way?) on the first output only:

```
[vMsgOriginal, errMsg] = Gateway_test_app(2);
vMsg = unit32(vMsgOriginal);
```

This assumes that you don't want to process your new string output through your `unit32` function.